# How to add custom data files to Roblox DataModel?

Tags: text, roblox

I don't seem to be able to add textual data (e.g. in CSV, JSON or XML files) to the Roblox [`DataModel`](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/DataModel), `Workspace`, `ServerStorage` or anywhere really?

Any hints on how to do this efficiently?
Ideally, Roblox should just give me the contents of the file as a [table](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html). But if there is a way to get a raw string from a file that I have to parse manually, I could cope, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866873/1938640) you cannot add "files" to the DataModel. However you can use the [HttpService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService) to load the data from a webserver (also [decode](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService/JSONDecode) and [encode](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService/JSONEncode) JSON).
If you do not want to load it that way, you can use a [Script](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Script) or [ModuleScript](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ModuleScript) to store data.

To make it easy, you can use [multiline strings](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial) (make sure to read about the "Nesting quotes") like so:

```
local data = [[Here is your
data that can
span over multiple lines,
so just copy-paste the content]]

print("My data: " .. data)
```

---

With ModuleScript:

```
return [[Here is your
data that can
span over multiple lines,
so just copy-paste the content]]
```

Usage of ModuleScript:

```
local data = require(game.ServerStorage.your.module.script.text.file)
print("My data: " .. data)
```

---

And if you want a JSON text to be decoded into a table:

```
local data = game:GetService("HttpService"):JSONDecode(require(game.ServerStorage.your.module.script.text.file))
```

Or in a ModuleScript:

```
return game:GetService("HttpService"):JSONDecode([[Here is your
data that can
span over multiple lines,
so just copy-paste the content]])
```

---

You could also store the text in a [StringValue](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/StringValue)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Roblox only allows for **their** files(RBXM, RBLX, etc.) to be inserted into studio. If it's a text file you want, I recommend just creating a new script instance and then copying the text over to that script.